# C# VS 2012 how to send string to other application in russian language?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, encoding, keyboard

C# Visual Studio 2012 how to send string to other application in Russian properly ?

i have in my application  .cs file Russian string, i want to send it to input of other application, i do so:

```
string str = "Демон бездны";
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(str);
```

But instead of this string i get:

```
    ????
```

symbols in return. I should somehow i think convert it to proper encoding but cant understand how.

also i tried to convert it to windows-1251 and it dint work out :(

```
    public static string Converter(string value, Encoding src, Encoding trg)
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        Decoder dec = src.GetDecoder();
        byte[] ba = trg.GetBytes(value);
        int len = dec.GetCharCount(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        char[] ca = new char[len];
        dec.GetChars(ba, 0, ba.Length, ca, 0);
        return new string(ca);
    }

    string line = Converter(str , Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
```

i also tried to simulate keypress like here: i tried this one [SendInput fails on 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962850/sendinput-fails-on-64bit) and it only works for English keys

using example key:

```
System.Convert.ToUInt16('Б');
```

and it works only for English key like

```
System.Convert.ToUInt16('G'); but not for Russian.
```

Finally got it worked:

```
    private const uint WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x0050;
    private const uint KLF_ACTIVATE = 1;
    private static string ru_RU = "00000419";
    private const string en_US = "00000409";


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hhwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);
```

usage (window that u change input should be active):

```
        PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, LoadKeyboardLayout(ru_RU, KLF_ACTIVATE));
```

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx: "If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided."

Comment: what function should i use then to send Russian text for it? Application is hearthstone game (Russian version).

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but does this work?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822053/vkkeyscanex-sendinput-alternative-for-unicode/8837883#8837883

Comment: for try this - where to get NativeWinApi ? i do not have this class  by default

Comment: Looks like that answer is incomplete.  They seem to be pinvoking [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I found an example of this here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput

Comment: its also only for english keys :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it took a bit more effort than I expected. The following successfully sends Unicode characters to another process (I tested with Word) from my WPF test executable.  Mostly this code is adapted from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput) but I found that if I sent two identical characters one after the other, the second was skipped, so I added a hack to prevent that:

```
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    internal InputType type;
    internal InputUnion U;
    internal static int Size
    {
        get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
    internal short wScan; // Use ScanCodeShort below for actual keypresses.
    internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal int time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

internal enum InputType : uint
{
    INPUT_MOUSE = 0,
    INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1,
    INPUT_HARDWARE = 2,
}

[Flags]
internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
{
    EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
    KEYUP = 0x0002,
    SCANCODE = 0x0008,
    UNICODE = 0x0004
}

// http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MOUSEINPUT.html
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    internal int dx;
    internal int dy;
    internal int mouseData;
    internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal uint time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[Flags]
internal enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
{
    ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
    HWHEEL = 0x01000,
    MOVE = 0x0001,
    MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
    LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
    LEFTUP = 0x0004,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
    VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
    WHEEL = 0x0800,
    XDOWN = 0x0080,
    XUP = 0x0100
}

// http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/HARDWAREINPUT.html
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    internal int uMsg;
    internal short wParamL;
    internal short wParamH;
}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
// and http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/KEYBDINPUT.html
internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Left mouse button
    ///</summary>
    LBUTTON = 0x01,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right mouse button
    ///</summary>
    RBUTTON = 0x02,
    ///<summary>
    ///Control-break processing
    ///</summary>
    CANCEL = 0x03,
    ///<summary>
    ///Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
    ///</summary>
    MBUTTON = 0x04,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X1 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X2 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
    ///<summary>
    ///BACKSPACE key
    ///</summary>
    BACK = 0x08,
    ///<summary>
    ///TAB key
    ///</summary>
    TAB = 0x09,
    ///<summary>
    ///CLEAR key
    ///</summary>
    CLEAR = 0x0C,
    ///<summary>
    ///ENTER key
    ///</summary>
    RETURN = 0x0D,
    ///<summary>
    ///SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    SHIFT = 0x10,
    ///<summary>
    ///CTRL key
    ///</summary>
    CONTROL = 0x11,
    ///<summary>
    ///ALT key
    ///</summary>
    MENU = 0x12,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAUSE key
    ///</summary>
    PAUSE = 0x13,
    ///<summary>
    ///CAPS LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    CAPITAL = 0x14,
    ///<summary>
    ///Input Method Editor (IME) Kana mode
    ///</summary>
    KANA = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hangul mode
    ///</summary>
    HANGUL = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Junja mode
    ///</summary>
    JUNJA = 0x17,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME final mode
    ///</summary>
    FINAL = 0x18,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hanja mode
    ///</summary>
    HANJA = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Kanji mode
    ///</summary>
    KANJI = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///ESC key
    ///</summary>
    ESCAPE = 0x1B,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME convert
    ///</summary>
    CONVERT = 0x1C,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME nonconvert
    ///</summary>
    NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME accept
    ///</summary>
    ACCEPT = 0x1E,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME mode change request
    ///</summary>
    MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
    ///<summary>
    ///SPACEBAR
    ///</summary>
    SPACE = 0x20,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE UP key
    ///</summary>
    PRIOR = 0x21,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE DOWN key
    ///</summary>
    NEXT = 0x22,
    ///<summary>
    ///END key
    ///</summary>
    END = 0x23,
    ///<summary>
    ///HOME key
    ///</summary>
    HOME = 0x24,
    ///<summary>
    ///LEFT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    LEFT = 0x25,
    ///<summary>
    ///UP ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    UP = 0x26,
    ///<summary>
    ///RIGHT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    RIGHT = 0x27,
    ///<summary>
    ///DOWN ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    DOWN = 0x28,
    ///<summary>
    ///SELECT key
    ///</summary>
    SELECT = 0x29,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT key
    ///</summary>
    PRINT = 0x2A,
    ///<summary>
    ///EXECUTE key
    ///</summary>
    EXECUTE = 0x2B,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT SCREEN key
    ///</summary>
    SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
    ///<summary>
    ///INS key
    ///</summary>
    INSERT = 0x2D,
    ///<summary>
    ///DEL key
    ///</summary>
    DELETE = 0x2E,
    ///<summary>
    ///HELP key
    ///</summary>
    HELP = 0x2F,
    ///<summary>
    ///0 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_0 = 0x30,
    ///<summary>
    ///1 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_1 = 0x31,
    ///<summary>
    ///2 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_2 = 0x32,
    ///<summary>
    ///3 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_3 = 0x33,
    ///<summary>
    ///4 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_4 = 0x34,
    ///<summary>
    ///5 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_5 = 0x35,
    ///<summary>
    ///6 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_6 = 0x36,
    ///<summary>
    ///7 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_7 = 0x37,
    ///<summary>
    ///8 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_8 = 0x38,
    ///<summary>
    ///9 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_9 = 0x39,
    ///<summary>
    ///A key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_A = 0x41,
    ///<summary>
    ///B key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_B = 0x42,
    ///<summary>
    ///C key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_C = 0x43,
    ///<summary>
    ///D key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_D = 0x44,
    ///<summary>
    ///E key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_E = 0x45,
    ///<summary>
    ///F key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_F = 0x46,
    ///<summary>
    ///G key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_G = 0x47,
    ///<summary>
    ///H key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_H = 0x48,
    ///<summary>
    ///I key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_I = 0x49,
    ///<summary>
    ///J key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_J = 0x4A,
    ///<summary>
    ///K key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_K = 0x4B,
    ///<summary>
    ///L key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_L = 0x4C,
    ///<summary>
    ///M key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_M = 0x4D,
    ///<summary>
    ///N key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_N = 0x4E,
    ///<summary>
    ///O key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_O = 0x4F,
    ///<summary>
    ///P key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_P = 0x50,
    ///<summary>
    ///Q key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Q = 0x51,
    ///<summary>
    ///R key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_R = 0x52,
    ///<summary>
    ///S key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_S = 0x53,
    ///<summary>
    ///T key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_T = 0x54,
    ///<summary>
    ///U key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_U = 0x55,
    ///<summary>
    ///V key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_V = 0x56,
    ///<summary>
    ///W key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_W = 0x57,
    ///<summary>
    ///X key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_X = 0x58,
    ///<summary>
    ///Y key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Y = 0x59,
    ///<summary>
    ///Z key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Z = 0x5A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left Windows key (Microsoft Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    LWIN = 0x5B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    RWIN = 0x5C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Applications key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    APPS = 0x5D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Computer Sleep key
    ///</summary>
    SLEEP = 0x5F,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 0 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 1 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 2 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 3 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 4 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 5 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 6 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 7 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 8 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 9 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
    ///<summary>
    ///Multiply key
    ///</summary>
    MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Add key
    ///</summary>
    ADD = 0x6B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Separator key
    ///</summary>
    SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Subtract key
    ///</summary>
    SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Decimal key
    ///</summary>
    DECIMAL = 0x6E,
    ///<summary>
    ///Divide key
    ///</summary>
    DIVIDE = 0x6F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F1 key
    ///</summary>
    F1 = 0x70,
    ///<summary>
    ///F2 key
    ///</summary>
    F2 = 0x71,
    ///<summary>
    ///F3 key
    ///</summary>
    F3 = 0x72,
    ///<summary>
    ///F4 key
    ///</summary>
    F4 = 0x73,
    ///<summary>
    ///F5 key
    ///</summary>
    F5 = 0x74,
    ///<summary>
    ///F6 key
    ///</summary>
    F6 = 0x75,
    ///<summary>
    ///F7 key
    ///</summary>
    F7 = 0x76,
    ///<summary>
    ///F8 key
    ///</summary>
    F8 = 0x77,
    ///<summary>
    ///F9 key
    ///</summary>
    F9 = 0x78,
    ///<summary>
    ///F10 key
    ///</summary>
    F10 = 0x79,
    ///<summary>
    ///F11 key
    ///</summary>
    F11 = 0x7A,
    ///<summary>
    ///F12 key
    ///</summary>
    F12 = 0x7B,
    ///<summary>
    ///F13 key
    ///</summary>
    F13 = 0x7C,
    ///<summary>
    ///F14 key
    ///</summary>
    F14 = 0x7D,
    ///<summary>
    ///F15 key
    ///</summary>
    F15 = 0x7E,
    ///<summary>
    ///F16 key
    ///</summary>
    F16 = 0x7F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F17 key  
    ///</summary>
    F17 = 0x80,
    ///<summary>
    ///F18 key  
    ///</summary>
    F18 = 0x81,
    ///<summary>
    ///F19 key  
    ///</summary>
    F19 = 0x82,
    ///<summary>
    ///F20 key  
    ///</summary>
    F20 = 0x83,
    ///<summary>
    ///F21 key  
    ///</summary>
    F21 = 0x84,
    ///<summary>
    ///F22 key, (PPC only) Key used to lock device.
    ///</summary>
    F22 = 0x85,
    ///<summary>
    ///F23 key  
    ///</summary>
    F23 = 0x86,
    ///<summary>
    ///F24 key  
    ///</summary>
    F24 = 0x87,
    ///<summary>
    ///NUM LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    NUMLOCK = 0x90,
    ///<summary>
    ///SCROLL LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    SCROLL = 0x91,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    LSHIFT = 0xA0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    RSHIFT = 0xA1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    LCONTROL = 0xA2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    RCONTROL = 0xA3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left MENU key
    ///</summary>
    LMENU = 0xA4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right MENU key
    ///</summary>
    RMENU = 0xA5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Back key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Forward key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Refresh key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Stop key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Search key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Favorites key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Start and Home key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Down key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Up key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Next Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Previous Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Stop Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Play/Pause Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Mail key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Select Media key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 1 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 2 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_1 = 0xBA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '+' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the ',' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '-' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '.' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_2 = 0xBF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_3 = 0xC0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_4 = 0xDB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_5 = 0xDC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_6 = 0xDD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_7 = 0xDE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_8 = 0xDF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
    ///</summary>
    OEM_102 = 0xE2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000/XP: IME PROCESS key
    ///</summary>
    PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes.
    ///The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information,
    ///see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
    ///</summary>
    PACKET = 0xE7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Attn key
    ///</summary>
    ATTN = 0xF6,
    ///<summary>
    ///CrSel key
    ///</summary>
    CRSEL = 0xF7,
    ///<summary>
    ///ExSel key
    ///</summary>
    EXSEL = 0xF8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Erase EOF key
    ///</summary>
    EREOF = 0xF9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Play key
    ///</summary>
    PLAY = 0xFA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Zoom key
    ///</summary>
    ZOOM = 0xFB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Reserved
    ///</summary>
    NONAME = 0xFC,
    ///<summary>
    ///PA1 key
    ///</summary>
    PA1 = 0xFD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Clear key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
}

internal enum ScanCodeShort : short
{
    LBUTTON = 0,
    RBUTTON = 0,
    CANCEL = 70,
    MBUTTON = 0,
    XBUTTON1 = 0,
    XBUTTON2 = 0,
    BACK = 14,
    TAB = 15,
    CLEAR = 76,
    RETURN = 28,
    SHIFT = 42,
    CONTROL = 29,
    MENU = 56,
    PAUSE = 0,
    CAPITAL = 58,
    KANA = 0,
    HANGUL = 0,
    JUNJA = 0,
    FINAL = 0,
    HANJA = 0,
    KANJI = 0,
    ESCAPE = 1,
    CONVERT = 0,
    NONCONVERT = 0,
    ACCEPT = 0,
    MODECHANGE = 0,
    SPACE = 57,
    PRIOR = 73,
    NEXT = 81,
    END = 79,
    HOME = 71,
    LEFT = 75,
    UP = 72,
    RIGHT = 77,
    DOWN = 80,
    SELECT = 0,
    PRINT = 0,
    EXECUTE = 0,
    SNAPSHOT = 84,
    INSERT = 82,
    DELETE = 83,
    HELP = 99,
    KEY_0 = 11,
    KEY_1 = 2,
    KEY_2 = 3,
    KEY_3 = 4,
    KEY_4 = 5,
    KEY_5 = 6,
    KEY_6 = 7,
    KEY_7 = 8,
    KEY_8 = 9,
    KEY_9 = 10,
    KEY_A = 30,
    KEY_B = 48,
    KEY_C = 46,
    KEY_D = 32,
    KEY_E = 18,
    KEY_F = 33,
    KEY_G = 34,
    KEY_H = 35,
    KEY_I = 23,
    KEY_J = 36,
    KEY_K = 37,
    KEY_L = 38,
    KEY_M = 50,
    KEY_N = 49,
    KEY_O = 24,
    KEY_P = 25,
    KEY_Q = 16,
    KEY_R = 19,
    KEY_S = 31,
    KEY_T = 20,
    KEY_U = 22,
    KEY_V = 47,
    KEY_W = 17,
    KEY_X = 45,
    KEY_Y = 21,
    KEY_Z = 44,
    LWIN = 91,
    RWIN = 92,
    APPS = 93,
    SLEEP = 95,
    NUMPAD0 = 82,
    NUMPAD1 = 79,
    NUMPAD2 = 80,
    NUMPAD3 = 81,
    NUMPAD4 = 75,
    NUMPAD5 = 76,
    NUMPAD6 = 77,
    NUMPAD7 = 71,
    NUMPAD8 = 72,
    NUMPAD9 = 73,
    MULTIPLY = 55,
    ADD = 78,
    SEPARATOR = 0,
    SUBTRACT = 74,
    DECIMAL = 83,
    DIVIDE = 53,
    F1 = 59,
    F2 = 60,
    F3 = 61,
    F4 = 62,
    F5 = 63,
    F6 = 64,
    F7 = 65,
    F8 = 66,
    F9 = 67,
    F10 = 68,
    F11 = 87,
    F12 = 88,
    F13 = 100,
    F14 = 101,
    F15 = 102,
    F16 = 103,
    F17 = 104,
    F18 = 105,
    F19 = 106,
    F20 = 107,
    F21 = 108,
    F22 = 109,
    F23 = 110,
    F24 = 118,
    NUMLOCK = 69,
    SCROLL = 70,
    LSHIFT = 42,
    RSHIFT = 54,
    LCONTROL = 29,
    RCONTROL = 29,
    LMENU = 56,
    RMENU = 56,
    BROWSER_BACK = 106,
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
    BROWSER_STOP = 104,
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
    BROWSER_HOME = 50,
    VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
    VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
    VOLUME_UP = 48,
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
    MEDIA_STOP = 36,
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
    OEM_1 = 39,
    OEM_PLUS = 13,
    OEM_COMMA = 51,
    OEM_MINUS = 12,
    OEM_PERIOD = 52,
    OEM_2 = 53,
    OEM_3 = 41,
    OEM_4 = 26,
    OEM_5 = 43,
    OEM_6 = 27,
    OEM_7 = 40,
    OEM_8 = 0,
    OEM_102 = 86,
    PROCESSKEY = 0,
    PACKET = 0,
    ATTN = 0,
    CRSEL = 0,
    EXSEL = 0,
    EREOF = 93,
    PLAY = 0,
    ZOOM = 98,
    NONAME = 0,
    PA1 = 0,
    OEM_CLEAR = 0,
}

internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern uint SendInput(
        uint nInputs,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
        int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern UIntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

    // For Windows Mobile, replace user32.dll with coredll.dll
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    // For Windows Mobile, replace user32.dll with coredll.dll
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
}

public static class Messaging
{
    public static bool SendString(string message)
    {
        return SendString(null, message);
    }

    public static bool SendString(string processName, string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            return false;
        IntPtr hWindow;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(processName))
            hWindow = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow();
        else
            hWindow = UnsafeNativeMethods.FindWindow(processName, null);
        if (hWindow == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;
        bool anySent = false;
        anySent = SendString(hWindow, message);
        return anySent;
    }

    public static bool SendString(IntPtr hWindow, string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return false;
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(hWindow);
        var inputs = new List<INPUT>(s.Length);
        char? prevChar = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char thisChar = s[i];
            if (thisChar == prevChar)
            {
                // Add a dummy to the list.  For some reason "SendInput()" merges identical adjacent keystrokes,
                // so prevent this with a null character.
                INPUT dummy = new INPUT();
                dummy.type = InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                dummy.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE;
                dummy.U.ki.wVk = 0;
                unchecked
                {
                    dummy.U.ki.wScan = (short)0;
                }
                inputs.Add(dummy);
            }
            INPUT input = new INPUT();
            input.type = InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE;
            input.U.ki.wVk = 0;
            unchecked
            {
                input.U.ki.wScan = (short)s[i];
            }
            inputs.Add(input);
            prevChar = thisChar;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Messaging.SendCharacter({0}, {1})", hWindow, s));
        var result = UnsafeNativeMethods.SendInput((uint)inputs.Count, inputs.ToArray(), INPUT.Size);
        if (result <= 0)
        {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("   Messaging.SendCharacter({0}, {1}): Error {2}: {3}", hWindow, s, error, new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(error).Message));
        }
        return result > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices, of which the comments above cover two.

At the higher level, Windows.Forms.SendKeys is working with Windows messages. You should be able to get something along these lines to work if you can get the right combination of Windows messages, but it's not entirely obvious how to go about it.

At the lower level, SendInput is inserting actual keystrokes into the keyboard buffer. This method would work for any kind of program (not just Windows) but these are keystrokes, not characters. For this to work with your Russian keyboard you would need to find the hardware scan code (which will have nothing to do with your Russian alphabet).

Alternatively it seems you can use KEYEVENTF_UNICODE and provide the Unicode character. This is the one I would go for. The character values used in .NET are already 16 bit numbers suitable for this purpose with need for encoding. Avoid UTF8 on Windows -- it won't help.

See: [SendInput fails on 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962850/sendinput-fails-on-64bit) for more info.