# Sendkeys doesnt work properly on PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, sendkeys

I want to paste strings on a pdf document from clipboard with sending keys "^(v)" or "^v" or "^{v}", but sometimes i see paste result like "v" where of string. How can i fix this problem?

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
```

Comment: You could try using SendInput, SendMessage or PostMessage through P/Invoke.

Comment: You could try using `Messaging.SendString()` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344066/c-sharp-vs-2012-how-to-send-string-to-other-application-in-russian-language/25346030#25346030.  For the unicode string, use the [unicode value of ^c](http://unicodelookup.com/#ctrl).