# C# - convert unicode character (of qwerty layout) to it's corresponding Keyboard (English) character

Tags: c#

For example, when non-English speaking people have their own language keyobards added in Windows, while typing in unicode language:

`qwerty`

becomes:

```
яшерты       //in Russian
手田水口廿卜  //in Chinese
ქწერტყ       //in Georgian
```

What can I use to convert those Unicode characters back to it's keyboard equivalents?  Or conversely, convert `qwerty` to specific language?

I've tried [unicode.net](https://github.com/neosmart/unicode.net) nuget package, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I don't find how "qwerty" could become "яшерты" in Russian. There may probably be a specific keyboard layout, but for default one this would result into "йцукен".

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/VkKeyScan.html

Comment: Ok, I have found it out. Apparently, there is a Russian [phonetic keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_keyboard_layout), which I personally never heard about and I am a native Russian speaker. As I said, ["йцукен"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCUKEN) is the most popular one. So, basically, you want a mapping of all existing (in Windows) keyboard layouts to the related keys on English qwerty keyboard.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev http://winrus.com/keyboard.htm

Comment: @T.Todua Amazing. Did never meet a single person using this one :) Perhaps, it makes more sense for non-native speakers or native bilinguals, because it is phonetic.

Comment: I dont know, just in our country, you can't meet anyone using other keyboard, than phonetic. Whatever the English char is on keyboard, on our keyboard it has it's coressponding char (which is pronounced as same phonetically). Actually, i dont know why phonetic keyoard is not universally used, as it seems logically appropriate..

Comment: Try to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344066/c-sharp-vs-2012-how-to-send-string-to-other-application-in-russian-language hope, it'll help

Comment: @HansPassant thanks! seems interesting

Answer (score -1):

Code below will return the current language layout that you use to type, even if it's different to your default keyboard language.

```
string lang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Do you want to use the keyboard or installed language culture info?